# Programatically open and close ion-datetime

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

Is there a way to open an ion-datetime programatically?

in Ionic 6 the ion-datetime is open all the time, but it can be hidden using an ion-modal and ion-datetime-button like this

```
        <ion-datetime-button #datetimeTrigger datetime="datetime"></ion-datetime-button>

        <ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
            <ng-template>
                <ion-datetime #datetime
                              id="datetime"
                              presentation="date"
                              (ionChange)="newDatePicked($event)"

                              (ionFocus)="handleDateFocus()"
                              (ionBlur)="handleDateBlur()"
                              [firstDayOfWeek]="1">
                </ion-datetime>
            </ng-template>
        </ion-modal>
```

I would like to open the date-time picker programatically because it is being triggered by an internal event

I can close it using `datetime.confirm(true)`.

*update*
I've managed to get it partially working, but involves rather more market than I was expecting

```
    <ion-datetime-button datetime="datetime" hidden></ion-datetime-button>
    <ion-button id="open-modal" hidden>X</ion-button>
    <ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true" trigger="open-modal" (didDismiss)="didDismiss()">
      ....
    </ion-modal>
```

When I want to open the dat time picker I do this

```
    document.getElementById('open-modal').click();
```

This works but it seems strange that I have to have both the ion-datetime-button and the ion-button. Programatically clicking on the ion-datetime-button does nothing, and removing it from the markup ruins the display of the date picker.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically fire the click event of the  which in turn will open the  as it is already referenced as the trigger.

component.ts

```
//declaration
@ViewChild('datetimeTrigger', { static: false }) datetimeTrigger: any;

// function
openDateTimeModal(){
  this.datetimeTrigger.el.click();
}
```

component.html

```
//specify view child component with #
<ion-datetime-button #datetimeTrigger datetime="datetime"></ion-datetime-button>
```

Comment: I could not get that to work, it keeps telling me 'underfed is not an object' as if datetimeTrigger has not been initialised or is out of scope. What I've got working at the moment is to add an ion-button with and ID and set that ID as the trigger of the ion-modal and then call click on the button. I'll add this to the question

Comment: @Craig please see my updated answer. Changing the ViewChild type and click event worked for me.

Comment: No change. I even added a `(click)=iWasClicked()` test function to the ion-date-button to prove it was receiving the click, which it was, but it does not trigger the ion-modal to open and show the ion-datetime

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually that when you open the `IonModal` via `IonDatetimeButton`'s datetime property alone, it doesn't seem to operate via `isOpen`. I don't know whether this is intended behavior or a bug. Anyway, when I explicitly use `isOpen` for opening (in addition to connecting via `id`), the closing works. Below is my working React implementation (with `const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);`).

```
<IonItem button={false}>
    <IonLabel>Date of Birth:</IonLabel>
    <IonDatetimeButton datetime='datepicker' onClick={() => { setShowModal(true); }}></IonDatetimeButton>
    <IonModal keepContentsMounted={true} isOpen={showModal}>
        <IonDatetime
            id="datepicker"
            presentation="date"
            max={maxDate}
            onIonChange={e => {
                setDateOfBirth(e.detail.value as string);
                setShowModal(false);
            }}
        />
    </IonModal>
</IonItem>
```

Comment: This looks like a react answer to an angular question